# failed to start session at login using ldap user

Tags: server, login, vmware, ldap

I have a ubuntu server 16.04 with ldap installed in vmware, and a ubuntu desktop 16.04 also in vmware. when I try to login using a ldap user I have created in phpldapadmin I get failed to start session, but when I login with a local user , I can login without any problems.
ping to and from server works also from client. 
but su in terminal to ldapuser does not work.

getent passwd shows there is connection to the server from client.
any ideas?